# I have a org.w3c.dom.Document and want to save it to my filesystem

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I create my pdf document out of a html File.
I want to save it to my Filesystem after creating it.
But i dont know how to save it... can you please help me saving this document? So that it is saved as a pdf then?

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setEntityResolver(FSEntityResolver.instance());

org.w3c.dom.document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");

baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(document, null);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(baos);
out.println(baos.toString());
baos.close();
```

Comment: You've got code using a ByteArrayOutputStream (which you're creating twice, for no obvious reason) - is that generating the right data?

Comment: ah sorry the second baos is false, i edit it out..
yes.. the printwriter returns me the correct pdf on the screen, but i want to save it!

Comment: Then change `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `FileOutputStream`...

Comment: @JonSkeet create an answer so you can claim your earned +25 points.

Comment: @RockyMM: I suppose as no-one else has answered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code you've got is correct as far as you're aware, but is simply writing to the wrong place (memory instead of a file) you just need to use a `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
try {
    renderer.createPDF(output);
} finally {
    output.close();
}
```